# why does ssh -t option adds cr & lf in redirected output

Tags: linux, ssh, io-redirection, cat

I connect from my windowsbox with putty to a linux box. After that I do the following:

on Server A:

```
serverA: file /etc/motd
/etc/motd: : ASCII English text
```

on Server B:

```
serverB: ssh -t user@serverA "cat /etc/motd" > /etc/motd.serverA
serverB: file /etc/motd.serverA
/etc/motd.serverA:  ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Why does the redericted output now have CR & LF? This happens only with the -t option from ssh. -t is needed if i need to run commands on a ssh login with sudo. like for example:

```
serverB: ssh -t user@serverA "sudo cat /etc/shadow" > /etc/shadow
```

Thanks for your sugestions

Answer (score 7):

Inspect the TTY settings.

```
$ ssh -t somewhere 'stty -a' | grep cr
iflags: -istrip icrnl -inlcr -igncr -iuclc ixon -ixoff ixany imaxbel
oflags: opost onlcr -ocrnl -onocr -onlret -olcuc oxtabs -onoeot
cflags: cread cs8 -parenb -parodd hupcl -clocal -cstopb -crtscts -mdmbuf
```

These may vary, but they show here that by default under `ssh -t` that `igncr` "ignore CR" is disabled on the input, and for output that `onlcr` is set (maps NL to CR-NL) and that CR are otherwise not mangled or omitted. One can lookup these terms in the `stty(1)` manual, and see also `termios(4)` (which linux may place in some other man section).

The settings can also be fiddled with (but this may however break things that do for some reason need `onlcr` set):

```
$ ssh -t somehost 'stty onlcr; cat /etc/motd' > x ; file x
x: ASCII English text, with CRLF line terminators
$ ssh -t somehost 'stty -onlcr; cat /etc/motd' > x ; file x
x: ASCII English text
$
```

It may be more sensible to instead use `scp` or `sftp` to copy data to eliminate the risk of (pseudo)tty CR/NL handling causing changes to file contents.

Comment: Thank your for your detailed answer. I can't use scp or sftp because my file is only root readable and a root login is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The `-t` option you're using to force a pseudo-tty allocation for your ssh session causes STDOUT to be line-buffered, because (in a nutshell) the shell assumes from the capabilities it's being told about, that you're using an interactive terminal.

So output is delivered in a way that would make sense in an interactive terminal.  Depending on what you're doing in that shell, and how your environment is set up, if you were to look more closely at the data, you might even see color codes, which may look like `[^[0;32m]`.

Sudo is an application that is designed to ask you for a password, hence the requirement for a TTY.  It wants to be able to effect terminal features to, a) ask you for a password to STDOUT, and b) mask the input that you provide back on STDIN from being displayed on STDOUT.

So, Sudo requires the `-t` and the `-t` line buffers output, so you see the additional control characters that would normally be interpreted by the terminal itself, and not passed along to STDOUT.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dos2unix utility to avoid configuration changes. I used this way and it worked for me.

```
remote_hostname=`ssh -t ${sys_ip} 'uname -n'|dos2unix`
```